# How to plot a sinus uniformly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

If I plot sinus like this

```
x=0:0.05:2*pi;
y=sin(x);
plot(x,y,'.-')
```

I'm getting obviously non-uniformly density of points.Please see attachment.[sin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo1U1.png)

What I want is, that points should be at the equivalent distance each other. So, I need to define x array somehow.. or is there is another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point density is uniform in `x`. If you want the points to be uniform in `y`, you could use:

```
y=-1:.05:1;
plot(asin(y),y,'o')
```

But then the points aren't uniform in `x`.

EDIT: Just for fun or for any future readers, to get points uniform in overall distance, the distance between points is `d=sqrt(h^2+(f(x+h)-f(x))^2)` which is approximately `d=h*sqrt(1+f'(x)^2)`, i.e. `h=d/sqrt(1+cos(x)^2)` in this case. The curve length is the integral of `sqrt(1+f'(x)^2)` which in this case is `4*sqrt(2)*ellipticE(1/2) = 7.6404`:

```
N = 100;
d = 7.6404/N;
x = zeros(1,N);
for n = 2:N
    x(n) = x(n-1) + d/sqrt(1+cos(x(n-1))^2);
end
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y,'x')
```

You can check that the distance between points is approximately constant by looking at `sqrt(diff(y).^2+diff(x).^2)`. It's only approximate because of the use of the derivative (at the left endpoint of the interval at that) for the distance, but this gets better as `N` increases. To get the distance exact, we'd need to numerically solve a trig equation for each point. The curve length is also affected by the approximation and tends to miss the last point.